# How to use sagemath to find nonlinear invariants of S-box?

Tags: block-cipher, attack, s-boxes

I read a paper about a nonlinear invariant attack that is ["Nonlinear Invariant Attack: Practical Attack on Full SCREAM, iSCREAM, and Midori64"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/732.pdf)

And I've found a website of sagemath : https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/21252 where they have a code to find nonlinear invariant for any S-box. But it's not official so it's not included in sagemath. Does anyone know how to do it? I want to write a code in C++ to find nonlinear invariant, but I don't get the idea of the author. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can get it from Sage.

Comment: @hola can you explain how to do it? I dont get the idea of the author. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the idea is simple. Compute the cycle decomposition of the S-box. If there are $t$ cycles, there are $2^t$ nonlinear invariants, that can be obtained by assigning 0 or 1 to each cycle.
For switching invariants ($f(S(x)) = f(x) + 1$), they may occur only if length of all cycles are even. Then assign 010101... or 101010... to each cycle, getting $2^t$ more invariants.